# Angular error:Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-routing

What I am trying to do is -

[image]

I am trying to add a form to the existing form but the data not getting stored

what the error coming up -

[image]

in the console its showing form connection is missing.. how can I connect it with following code I have?

The code behind the click is something like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" routerLink="../viewemployee" [disabled]="empForm.invalid">Add Employee</button>
```

please refer the link below for the code.. need help to move on from this to solve other tasks.

If it is required to post the code here as well, I will do.Please answer and respond.
Thanx in advance.

**[How to connect the form in angular routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404250/how-to-connect-the-form-in-angular-routing)**

createemployee.component.html

```
<h2>Add Employee:</h2>
      <form class="form-horizontal" #empForm="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="name"  minlength="4" maxlength="10"  pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]\S*$" [(ngModel)]="model.name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                   #name="ngModel" required/>
            <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                Name is required.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="name.errors.pattern">
                No Spaces
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
                Name must be at least 4 characters long.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="position">Position:</label>

          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="position" minlength="4" maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z]*$" [(ngModel)]="model.position" placeholder="Enter your position"
                   #position="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="position.invalid && (position.dirty || position.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="position.errors.required">
                Position is required.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="position.errors.pattern">
                Only Alphabets are must be entered
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="position.errors.minlength">
                Position must be at least 4 characters long.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="salary">Salary:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salary" pattern="[0-9]*"
                   minlength="5" maxlength="7"  [(ngModel)]="model.salary" placeholder="Enter Salary" #salary="ngModel" required />
            <div *ngIf="salary.invalid && (salary.dirty || salary.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="salary.errors.required">
                Salary is required.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="salary.errors.minlength">
                Salary must be in 5 numbers.
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="salary.errors.maxlength">
                Salary must not be exceeded morethan 7 numbers.
              </div>

              <div *ngIf="salary.errors?.pattern">Only numebers should be typed
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" routerLink="../viewemployee" [disabled]="empForm.invalid">Add Employee</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" routerLink="../home">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the html form as well?

Comment: yes i will.. but if u want u can check the code in the link posted below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404250/how-to-connect-the-form-in-angular-routing

Answer (score -3):

You could change your component as follows:

Add event handler to the form:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="continue()">
```

Handle the routing in code:

```
continue() {
  ...
  this.router.navigateByUrl("../viewemployee");
}
```

You need to inject the router:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}
```